# SSRS HEADER CHANGE (Change column name)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have the following table in which I have already calculated the 95 percentile in SQL SERVER 2012.I want to produce the report in SSRS 2008R2. But when I place [95th%ile] in SSRS table column, it change the header to [ID95th ile]. Is there a way I can change it to [95th%ile] as this is what is in the current excel report and I have been told not to change it to any other name
Below is sample data that I am using.

```
CREATE TABLE ##PerCent (month Varchar(10), Percentile INT)
INSERT INTO ##PerCent
VALUES
('Jan',153),
('Feb',171),
('Mar',141)

SELECT 
month,
Percentile  AS '95th%ile'
FROM ##PerCent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add a field which name starts with numbers or any character different to a letter.

[image]

However you can change the name in the tablix header if you are presenting the dataset in that component.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.